# How to get a line in SQL Database Table to Print in Textboxes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table "Salespeople" with the parameters first name, last name, address, city, state, and phone number.

I search for an individual entry in this database, and I want the results for 1 entry to print in their respective textboxes for user editing. I keep getting an SQL exception and I'm not sure which code to use now.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myconnection As New SqlConnection("server=classified;database=classified")
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim thePhoneQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Salespeople WHERE [First Name]=@FirstName AND [Last Name]=@LastName AND [Phone Number]=@PhoneNumber"
    Dim phoneValidator As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(thePhoneQuery, myconnection)
    BindGridSelectedSalespeople()
    phoneValidator.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox1.Text)
    phoneValidator.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox2.Text)
    phoneValidator.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox3.Text + "-" + TextBox4.Text + "-" + TextBox5.Text)
    Using reader As SqlDataReader = phoneValidator.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            ' User already exists
            MsgBox("This salesperson already exists in the database.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Label8.Visible = True
            Label9.Visible = True
            Label10.Visible = True
            Label11.Visible = True
            Label12.Visible = True
            Label13.Visible = True
            Label14.Visible = True
            Label15.Visible = True

            TextBox6.Visible = True
            TextBox7.Visible = True
            TextBox8.Visible = True
            TextBox9.Visible = True
            TextBox10.Visible = True
            TextBox11.Visible = True
            TextBox12.Visible = True
            TextBox13.Visible = True

            While (reader.Read())
                TextBox6.Text = reader.Read
                TextBox7.Text = (reader("@LastName"))
                TextBox8.Text = (reader("@Address"))
                TextBox9.Text = (reader("@City"))
                TextBox10.Text = (reader("@State"))


            End While
        Else
            reader.Close()
            MsgBox("The Salesperson '" + TextBox1.Text + "' '" + TextBox2.Text + "' does not exist. Please check the name and try again, or add them as a new salesperson.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)



        End If
    End Using
    myconnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: what SQL exception you are getting?

Comment: don't call `reader.Read` twice.

Comment: The string in the reader - `reader("Lastname")` should not contain the `@` symbol.

Comment: Assuming I kept the While (reader.Read()) Statement in there, what should I put for each of the textbox assignments?

I.e. When I put ("[First Name]").ToString() I literally get "[First Name]" printed. When I put read in front of it I get an unhandled SQL exception.

Comment: I used convert.tostring(reader.getsqlstring(#)) and it worked

Comment: `reader.item("Last Name").ToString`  you can also read by index, but that is easier when your query is not "SELECT * ..."

Answer (score 0):

I used convert.tostring(reader.getsqlstring(#)) and it worked

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myconnection As New SqlConnection("server=classified;database=classified")
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim thePhoneQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Salespeople WHERE [First Name]=@FirstName AND [Last Name]=@LastName AND [Phone Number]=@PhoneNumber"
    Dim phoneValidator As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(thePhoneQuery, myconnection)
    BindGridSelectedSalespeople()
    phoneValidator.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox1.Text)
    phoneValidator.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox2.Text)
    phoneValidator.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox3.Text + "-" + TextBox4.Text + "-" + TextBox5.Text)
    Using reader As SqlDataReader = phoneValidator.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            ' User already exists
            MsgBox("This salesperson already exists in the database.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Label8.Visible = True
            Label9.Visible = True
            Label10.Visible = True
            Label11.Visible = True
            Label12.Visible = True
            Label13.Visible = True
            Label14.Visible = True
            Label15.Visible = True

            TextBox6.Visible = True
            TextBox7.Visible = True
            TextBox8.Visible = True
            TextBox9.Visible = True
            TextBox10.Visible = True
            TextBox11.Visible = True
            TextBox12.Visible = True
            TextBox13.Visible = True

            While (reader.Read())
                TextBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetSqlString(0))
                TextBox7.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetSqlString(1))
                TextBox8.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetSqlString(2))
                TextBox9.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetSqlString(3))
                TextBox10.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetSqlString(4))
                TextBox11.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetSqlString(5)).Substring(0, 3)
                TextBox12.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetSqlString(5)).Substring(4, 3)
                TextBox13.Text = Convert.ToString(reader.GetSqlString(5)).Substring(8, 4)
            End While
        Else
            reader.Close()
            MsgBox("The Salesperson '" + TextBox1.Text + "' '" + TextBox2.Text + "' does not exist. Please check the name and try again, or add them as a new salesperson.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)



        End If
    End Using
    myconnection.Close()
End Sub
```